# Injecting (implicit) value of abstract type into subtypes of trait

Tags: scala, types, traits, type-parameter, path-dependent-type

Here is a simplification of my scenario that I am trying to make it work

```
// the UnrelatedN are mostly used as tag traits, for type-checking purposes
trait Unrelated1
trait Unrelated2

trait HasUnrelatedSupertrait {
  type Unrelated  // abstract type
}

trait HasUnrelated[... /*TODO: Parametrize with (factory of) UnrelatedN*/]
    extends HasUnrelatedSupertrait {
  type Unrelated = UnrelatedType  // path-dependent type
  implicit val unrelated = ... // instantiate or access (singleton) instance of Unrelated
}

trait Subtype1 extends HasUnrelated[/* Something involving Unrelated1 */] with ...
trait Subtype2 extends HasUnrelated[/* Something involving Unrelated2 */] with ...
// ... (many more similar subtypes)
```

Basically, I would like to *inject the implicit val instance of
abstract type* into (subtypes of) `HasUnrelated` in a non-intrusive
way, hopefully through a type parameter that I have some flexibility
over (see TODO).

(I don't care if Unrelated1/2 instances are constructed via new,
factory and how those factories are defined (as objects, classes
etc.), as long as I can get 2 distinct instances of Unrelated1/2.)

Some of the constraining factors why my attempts have failed are:

- `HasUnrelated` and `HasUnrelatedSupertrait` must be traits, not classes
- traits cannot have parameters (so I cannot pass (implicit) val factory)
- traits cannot have context or view bounds (to bring in ClassTag/TypeTag)
- I am not willing to clutter all the subtypes of `HasUnrelated` with
  additional type/val declarations

However, I am willing to do one or more of the following changes:

- introduce (singleton) factories for Unrelated1/2
- introduce arbitrary inheritance in Unrelated1/2 as long as those
  types are still unrelated (neither is subtype of the other)
- add supertype to `HasUnrelated` as long is it requires extra
  declarations (if any) *only* in `HasUnrelated`, but not any of its subtypes

Is there a way to achieve this in Scala and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Probably type class is something you are looking for? Consider this example

```
trait Companion[T] {
  val comp: T
}

object Companion {
  def apply[T: Companion] = implicitly[Companion[T]]
}

object UnrelatedType {
  implicit val thisComp = 
    new Companion[UnrelatedType.type] { 
      val comp = UnrelatedType 
    }
}

// Somewhere later
type Unrelated = UnrelatedType
implicit val unrelated = Companion[UnrelatedType]
```

Comment: In my case, `unrelated` needs to be a *term*, which is constructed
either via `new` or by accessing another *instance* of `UnrelatedType`,
which *must be* a type parameter of the enclosing trait
`HasUnrelated`.  AFAIK, in order for type classes to work, implicit
objects need to be in scope (in my case within the `HasUnrelated`
trait).  In your case, all I see is bringing values (objects) as types into
global scope. Would you mind explaining how is your example
applicable to my case? Thanks.